# Import files in docker compose with volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to import a couple of files in my docker-compose project to be able to read them and use them in a gunicorn file configuration. Here is my current docker compose:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db: 
    container_name: my_table_postgres
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432/tcp
    volumes:
      - my_table_postgres_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=my_table_postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=dev
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Ieyh5&RIR48!&8fc

  redis: 
    container_name: redis
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6739:6739/tcp
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis-oauth-user-service
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/var/lib/redis/data/

  my_table:
    container_name: my_table
    build: .
    command: ["python", "-m", "gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000", "-c", "gunicorn.conf.py", "mytable.wsgi"]
    volumes:
      - .:/api
      - certs:/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.my-table.it
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  celery:
    image: celery
    container_name: celery
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: ['python', '-m', 'celery', '-A', 'mytable' ,'worker', '-l', 'INFO']
    volumes:
      - .:/api
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - my_table
    links:
      - redis

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - my_table

volumes:
  my_table_postgres_db:
  redis_data:
```

And here are the lines that I am using to read the files:

```
certfile = "fullchain.pem"
keyfile = "privkey.pem"
```

But each time I run, the following error occurs:

```
table    |     client = ssl.wrap_socket(client, server_side=True,
my_table    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_table    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1443, in wrap_socket
my_table    |     context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
my_table    | IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory
```

So that means that the path is incorrect. How can I fix the path in the docker compose file and also in the other file, in order to make them meet together and use the correct file?

Thank you a lot

Here is the Dockerfile as suggested from the comments:

```
FROM python:3.11

# Managing user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash devuser
USER devuser
WORKDIR /home/devuser

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY --chown=devuser:devuser requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --user --default-timeout=1000 --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --user --default-timeout=1000 -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

COPY --chown=devuser:devuser . .

ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it's reported as a directory, can you share your file tree? The `Dockerfile` will also help.

---

Assuming that `fullchain.pem` and `privkey.pem` are inside the `certs` folder, you'd need to provide the path to these files in your configuration. As you're mounting `.` to `/api`, you can use the configuration below:

```py
certfile = "certs/fullchain.pem"
keyfile = "certs/privkey.pem"
```

This again will work only if your work directory is set to `/api` in your container image.

Comment: I just added the docker file

Comment: Please share contents of `entrypoint.sh`, and the file tree